# CakePHP condition contain multi level model

Tags: cakephp-2.0, conditional-statements, contains, multi-level

I want to write a condition for my second level PersonneBien where should I write the condition

```
      $this->Reservation->find('all',array('conditions' =>    array('Reservation.idBien' => 9),'contain' => array('Bien'=>array('BiensPersonne'))
```

when I write debug

```
     array(
    (int) 0 => array(
    'Reservation' => array(
        'idReser' => '1',
        'dateReserDu' => '2016-04-23',
        'dateReserAu' => '2016-04-27',
        'montantAPaye' => '500',
        'etatReservation' => 'Reserve',
        'iddev' => '0',
        'idBien' => '9',
        'id' => '24'
    ),
    'Bien' => array(
        'idBien' => '9',
        'designBien' => 'Petit coeur a TUNIS ville',
        'aPropos' => 'De Host � Milan tres apprecie, avec environ 700 re positifs me trouver en Tunisie quelques jours par mois. Je lai choisi, ici aussi, d'avoir ma maison ou trouver ma souffrance et mes souvenirs. Les couleurs et les objets mediterraneens trouve et rec',
        'capaciteAccueil' => '3',
        'nbSalleBain' => '1',
        'nbChambre' => '2',
        'nbLits' => '3',
        'description' => 'De Host a Milan beaucoup apprecie, avec environ    700 commentaires positifs 
        'adresse' => 'rue ladikiya',
        'immeuble' => '',
        'affichable' => false,
        'affichablePageAccueil' => false,
        'idtypelogement' => '1',
        'idVille' => '14',
        'idPays' => '1',
        'idTypeBien' => '2',
        'posLat' => '36.8065',
        'posLong' => '10.1815',
        'BiensPersonne' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        )
    )
       )
         )
```

Where should I write the condition?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `Contain` `array` you can add conditions to second level association like follows

```
$this->Reservation->find('all',
          array(
            'conditions' =>array('Reservation.idBien' => 9),
            'contain' => array('Bein'=>array('conditions'=>array('BiensPersonne'=>'condition_value')))
          );
```

Comment: it not work it show me  Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'BiensPersonne.personne_id' in 'on clause'
SQL Query: SELECT `Reservation`.`idReser`, `Reservation`.`dateReserDu`, `Reservation`.`dateReserAu`, `Reservation`.`montantAPaye`, `Reservation`.`etatReservation`, `Reservation`.`iddev`, `Reservation`.`idBien`, `Reservation`.`id`, `Bien`.`idBien`, `Bien`.`designBien`,`Bien`.`adresse`,` FROM `projet`.`reservations` AS `Reservation` LEFT JOIN `projet`.`biens` AS `Bien` ON (`Reservation`.`idBien` = `Bien`.`idBien` AND `BiensPersonne`.`personne_id` = '1') WHERE 1 = 1

Comment: i write $this->Reservation->find('all',
          array(
            'contain' => array('Bien'=>array('conditions'=>array('BiensPersonne.personne_id'=>$this->Session->read('Auth.User.0.Personne.id'))))
          ));  it not work

Comment: yeah i have in the Bien Controllers public $hasMany = array('BiensPersonne' ); andvar $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Personne');    it is HABTM  : i have class bien hve idBien and class personne have id and class BiensPersonne have id, personne_id and bien_id

Comment: Try this one
$this->Reservation->find('all',array('conditions' =>array('Reservation.idBien' => 9),'contain' => array('Bein','Bein.BiensPersonne'=>array('conditions'=>array('BiensPersonne.personne_id'=>$this->Sess‌​ion->read('Auth.User.0.Personne.id')))));

Comment: it show the same probleme  Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'BiensPersonne.pers‌​onne_id' in 'where clause'
SQL Query: SELECT `BiensPersonne`.`id`, `BiensPersonne`.`bien_id`, `BiensPersonne`.`personne_id` FROM `projet`.`biens_personnes` AS `BiensPersonne` WHERE `BiensPersonne`.`pers‌​onne_id` = '1' AND `BiensPersonne`.`bien_id` = (9)

Comment: give me some time I will try to figure out... :)